# Finding the longest chain of same-type nodes

Tags: algorithm, actionscript, graph, nodes

I have a tree structure of interconnected nodes of various types. Each node keeps track of which nodes it is connected to. In this structure I need to find the longest unconnected chain or path of same type nodes.

I've read up on graphs and breadth/depth first searches but these don't quite yield the results I need. (they'll find a chain but also include all the dead end branches between an origin and destination node)

Is there an existing algorithm for this purpose?

Comment: The longest *unconnected* chain? If you're looking for a chain, I assume you would want those nodes to be *connected*? Could you clarify?

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit more, since if each node keeps track of nodes it is connected to, it looks like you have a graph that has connnected components, and for each node type, find the number of connected components that node type is found in, the one present in most connected components is the type that has the longest unconnected chain. is that what you meant?

Comment: I think what the author is indicating is that he might get a graph back like ((A->B),(A->F),(B->C),(C->D),(D->E)).  A through F are all the same nodetype.  But he wants any branches, such as A->F trimmed from the graph.  This presents a problem in the case of ((M->N),(N->O),(M->P),(P->Q)) since there are two equal length branches in the same tree -- which do you prune?

Answer (score 0):

**If by "chain" you mean connected component, then**

Say your graph has edges E and vertices V.

Iterate over the edges, deleting all edges connecting nodes of a different type. This is O(|E|).

Find the the connected components, using depth-first or breadth-first. This is O(|E|+|V|).

The largest connected component will be the longest chain of same-type nodes.

**If by chain you mean simple cycle** (starts, stops at same node, doesn't revisit any nodes), then this is NP complete. If the connected components are small, it should be feasible none the less.

**If by chain you mean simple path**, then this is NP-Hard.